# Mic record on button click

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript, audio-recording

I'm trying to get the mic to record when I press on a button (`onClick`). The mic can capture and playback if I put the code into `function Start()`. Could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong to make this work with an `onClick` button action?

```
#pragma strict

static var reco : AudioClip;

function onClick() {
    var aud = GetComponent.<AudioSource>();
    reco = Microphone.Start("Built-in Microphone", false, 2, 44100);
    aud.clip = reco;
    aud.Play()
}
```

Comment: what happens when you debug your click?

Comment: Good thinking! I found that it was indeed recording, just that it wasn't playing the audio from the same function call.

Comment: @Frohlich Would you happen to know how I can playback this microphone recording from another script during the same execution run? I don't need the recording to be saved, just to persist from scene to scene and to be able to playback from different scripts.

Comment: What if you just record directly into your aud.clip instead of point it to another audioclip? Still have problems?

Comment: Good catch @Frohlich! The solution to my follow-up question is http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/10857/how-can-i-access-other-scripts-and-their-functions.html

Though I have chosen to implement this instead http://docs.unity3d.com/410/Documentation/ScriptReference/index.Accessing_Other_Game_Objects.html

Could you add your first response as an answer and I'll choose that as the answer?

Thank you :-)

Comment: in fact I didn't noticed that you was using unity script instead of C# ( as I always use C# I tend to focus on commands and avoid declarations so "function" onClick() and #pragma passed me =p ), I think you should get user3071284 answer as he catch this before ;)

Comment: I never got the audio to play while recording from the onClick function. Instead, I used a different solution which was to play the audio from a different function.

Answer (score 1):

Your call to GetComponent is using some C#. Change that line to the following:

```
var aud = gameObject.GetComponent(AudioSource);
```

Comment: That's interesting. I have found that all of these variations work with my code. Although this had not solved my original issue.
1. var lessonAud = GetComponent.<AudioSource>();
2. var lessonAud = GetComponent(AudioSource);
3. var lessonAud = gameObject.GetComponent(AudioSource);

Comment: I never got the audio to play while recording from the onClick function. Instead, I used a different solution which was to play the audio from a different function.

Comment: That is interesting. I based my answer here on what's described in JS tab of  the official doc page for GetComponent. http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html

Comment: The initial code above works when it's in a Start function, though it doesn't have the same behavior when placed into an onClick function

Comment: Does this answer help? http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/974622/unity-502f1-ui-button-onclick-function.html

Comment: No, the onClick function was executing, but all the calls inside the onClick wasn't going off.